# How do I define a counter which resets whenever a display equation environment is entered?

Tags: equations, counters

I'd like to have a counter that resets whenever a display math environment is entered, *numbered or not*.  How do I accomplish that?

The code below produces zeros only for the actual equation environments.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{mycounter}[equation]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{23}  
\begin{equation}
x\themycounter
\end{equation}

\setcounter{mycounter}{23}
\[
y\themycounter
\]

\setcounter{mycounter}{23}
\begin{multline}
a\\=b\themycounter
\end{multline}


\begin{equation}
z\themycounter
\end{equation}
Counter mycounter should reset in any equation--like environment, numbered or not.
\end{document}
```

Comment: A bit risky, but `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}` might work.

Comment: What's risky about it?

Comment: Not _risky_ in the strict sense of the word, but there might be some code which carelessly changes the contents of `\everydisplay`, or some code which _relies_ on the contents of `\everydisplay`. In the former case, your setting will be lost and your code won't work. In the latter case something _might_ break badly. You just need to have in mind that it may break something, somewhere. If it doesn't, go for it :-)

Comment: Thank you @PhelypeOleinik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align*}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{gather}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{gather*}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multline}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multline*}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{mycounter}{23}  
\begin{equation}
x\themycounter
\end{equation}

\setcounter{mycounter}{23}
\[
y\themycounter
\]

\setcounter{mycounter}{23}
\begin{multline}
a\\=b\themycounter
\end{multline}

\begin{align}
z\themycounter&=y\\
t\themycounter&=u
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
z\themycounter&=y\\
t\themycounter&=u
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```